# Apache2 crashing sometimes - gets working just after an apache2 restart - why is this happening?

Tags: server, apache2, crash

I have an Ubuntu Server (Amazon AWS).

I never encountered any problems with it untill it started crashing. (website doesn't load).

I thought it's because of too much traffic entering the server, so I moved from a micro instance to a large instance.

The server continued crashing!

This is the last outputs that I have in `var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
[Sun Jan 31 11:59:28.743031 2016] [core:notice] [pid 25004] AH00051: child pid 26843 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 31 11:59:28.743068 2016] [core:notice] [pid 25004] AH00051: child pid 29611 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 31 11:59:28.743104 2016] [core:notice] [pid 25004] AH00051: child pid 25756 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 31 11:59:28.743142 2016] [core:notice] [pid 25004] AH00051: child pid 26009 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 31 11:59:28.743179 2016] [core:notice] [pid 25004] AH00051: child pid 29658 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 31 11:59:28.743221 2016] [core:notice] [pid 25004] AH00051: child pid 27018 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 31 11:59:28.743258 2016] [core:notice] [pid 25004] AH00051: child pid 25403 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 31 11:59:28.743297 2016] [core:notice] [pid 25004] AH00051: child pid 31635 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 31 11:59:28.743336 2016] [core:notice] [pid 25004] AH00051: child pid 32218 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Jan 31 11:59:28.743359 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 25004] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Jan 31 11:59:29.561943 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4642] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jan 31 11:59:29.561981 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4642] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Jan 31 11:59:37.917268 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 4660] [client 46.19.86.35:42838] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/images$
[Sun Jan 31 12:00:21.260865 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4642] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Jan 31 12:00:22.315790 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7979] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jan 31 12:00:22.315823 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7979] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Jan 31 12:50:09.728092 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 8710] [client 104.156.75.50:62868] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/imag$
[Sun Jan 31 13:13:47.748077 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 8710] [client 37.19.121.111:53364] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/imag$
[Sun Jan 31 14:53:02.170028 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 8884] [client 86.57.138.111:49984] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/imag$
[Sun Jan 31 15:40:53.798238 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 9054] [client 212.199.50.111:5320] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/imag$
[Sun Jan 31 22:18:25.572249 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 9626] [client 105.158.234.111:50437] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/im$
[Sun Jan 31 22:48:08.829047 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 9625] [client 46.117.205.111:51840] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/ima$
[Mon Feb 01 01:58:36.329369 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 9885] [client 223.135.99.111:59622] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/imag$
[Mon Feb 01 08:15:16.526188 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7979] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Feb 01 08:15:17.587765 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10943] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 01 08:15:17.587795 2016] [core:notice] [pid 10943] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Feb 01 08:53:35.275526 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10943] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Feb 01 08:53:36.336817 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11187] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 01 08:53:36.336857 2016] [core:notice] [pid 11187] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Feb 01 08:56:39.238785 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 11200] [client 31.168.28.111:49379] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/ima$
[Mon Feb 01 08:56:44.889830 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 11204] [client 31.168.28.111:49460] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/ima$
[Mon Feb 01 08:57:01.744676 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 11202] [client 31.168.28.111:49569] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/ima$
[Mon Feb 01 08:57:25.535356 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 11194] [client 31.168.28.111:49741] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/ima$
[Mon Feb 01 13:07:40.230474 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 11195] [client 89.246.253.111:60831] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/ima$
[Mon Feb 01 14:08:03.296473 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 11992] [client 62.90.96.111:51718] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/imag$
[Mon Feb 01 14:41:48.731256 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11187] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Feb 01 14:46:07.814463 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1275] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 01 14:46:07.814773 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1275] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Feb 01 14:58:43.794056 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1275] AH00052: child pid 1500 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Feb 01 14:58:43.794092 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1275] AH00052: child pid 1487 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Feb 01 14:58:43.794128 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1275] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Feb 01 14:59:19.780338 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1240] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 01 14:59:19.780677 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1240] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Feb 01 15:00:54.743287 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1240] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Feb 01 15:01:36.836172 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1241] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 01 15:01:36.836545 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1241] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

From what I understood it's a problem with the indexes (?) which I don't really understand why suddenly now I have problems with since I have never had any.

so I edited the file `etc/apache2/apache2.conf` from:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I'm not even sure that this was the problem that cause all this.

Can you please give me your opinion about this and help me maybe solve this for good?